# IBM IOT code for publishing and subscribing Topics

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

Hey i am new to IBM IOT but i am not getting the easy way to publish and subscribe the topic using paho-mqtt. If there is any good documentation please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the ibm iot python sdk. You can find installation instructions here:
https://ibm-watson-iot.github.io/iot-python/

below is a sample code on how you can connect and publish events

https://ibm-watson-iot.github.io/iot-python/device/#sample-code

```
import wiotp.sdk.device

def myCommandCallback(cmd):
    print("Command received: %s" % cmd.data)

# Configure
myConfig = wiotp.sdk.device.parseConfigFile("device.yaml")
client = wiotp.sdk.device.DeviceClient(config=myConfig, logHandlers=None)
client.commandCallback = myCommandCallback

# Connect
client.connect()

# Send Data
myData={'name' : 'foo', 'cpu' : 60, 'mem' : 50}
client.publishEvent(eventId="status", msgFormat="json", data=myData, qos=0, onPublish=None)

# Disconnect
client.disconnect()
```

and example of the device.yaml is

```
myConfig = { 
    "identity": {
        "orgId": "org1id",
        "typeId": "raspberry-pi-3"
        "deviceId": "00ef08ac05"
    }.
    "auth" {
        "token": "Ab$76s)asj8_s5"
    }
}
client = wiotp.sdk.device.DeviceClient(config=myConfig)
```

The above information can be obtained from the IoT Platform interface

Comment: This is coool thank.you so much for helping me great and easy answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how I subscribe to events in IBM Watson IoT Platform Javascript SDK:

```
import { ApplicationClient, ApplicationConfig } from '@wiotp/sdk';

let identity = {
  orgId: 'orgId',
  typeId: 'typeId',
  deviceId: 'deviceId'
};

let auth = {
  key: 'key',
  token: 'token'
};

let options = {
  domain: 'internetofthings.ibmcloud.com',
  apiRoot: null,
  logLevel: 'info',
  mqtt: {
    port: 8883,
    transport: 'tcp',
    cleanStart: true,
    sessionExpiry: 3600,
    keepAlive: 60,
    sharedSubscription: false,
    caFile: null
  },
  http: { verify: true }
};

let appConfig = new ApplicationConfig(identity, auth, options);
let appClient = new ApplicationClient(appConfig);

appClient.connect();

appClient.on('connect', function () {
  console.log(`Connected to organization on IBM Watson IoT Platform`);
  appClient.subscribeToEvents();
});

appClient.on("deviceEvent", function (typeId, deviceId, eventId, format, payload) {
  console.log("Device Event from :: " + typeId + " : " + deviceId + " of event " + eventId + " with format " + format + " - payload = " + payload);
});
```

Comment: Great answer! To make it complete, could you also add how you publish to events?